# ¿Hay alguna forma de repetir una acción n veces en Javascript sin necesidad de manejar variables de incremento?

Tags: javascript, bucles

Lo que quiero saber es si en Javascript hay alguna forma de repetir una acción `n` veces sin tener que usar el tradicional bucle `for` en el cual hay una variable mutable que va cambiando a cada paso del bucle.

Por ejemplo, este código funciona:

```
var myTotal = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < myTotal; i++) {
  console.log("hola");
}
```

Pero como se puede ver, la variable mutable `i` no me interesa para nada, yo sólo quiero imprimir `hola` 4 veces y nada más. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo, sin tener que recurrir a `i`?

Encontré código que funciona con arrays, pero no con valores numéricos, como es el caso de `myTotal`.

> **NOTA:** No busco una función personalizada que lo haga, lo que quiero saber es si hay forma de hacer esto desde Javascript mismo.

```js
/*Con arrays no hay problema*/
var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];
myArray.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log("hola");
});


for (let i of myArray) {
  console.log("hola");
}

/*Con un número, ¿hay otra forma diferente de esta?*/
var myTotal = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < myTotal; i++) {
  console.log("hola");
}
```

Comment: también la primer forma usando el array : `var myArray  = new Array(myTotal);`

Comment: No existe ningún modo que sea igual de eficiente, que yo sepa

Answer (score 4):

Con un repeat y un eval:

```js
var myTotal = 4
eval("console.log('hola');".repeat(myTotal));
```

Con eval y Join:

```js
var myTotal = 4
eval(Array(myTotal+1).join("console.log('hola');"));
```

repeat y new function

```js
var myTotal = 4
var strCode = "console.log('hola');".repeat(myTotal);
(new Function(strCode))();
```

Comment: aunque me da la sensación que al usar arrays si N es muy grande el rendimiento decae y el for con índice es lo mas cercano al bytecode de repetir algo n veces

Comment: La primera solución es lo que mismo que `console.log('hola');console.log('hola');console.log('hola');console.log('hola')`

Answer (score -1):

Con un `repeat` y *Template literals (Template strings)*:

```js
let myTotal = 4;
console.log(`${('hola ').repeat(myTotal)}`);
```